# Two Coins are Flipped n Times

Tags: probability-distributions

So two people are flipping a fair coin $n$ times each. What's the probability that they both flip the same number of heads?

My current approach was to use a binomial, and sum up the cases when X (no of heads) = 0,1,...,n 
But was wondering if there was a better approach, i.e from sum of variables or a generating function for each pair of flips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call these people Alice and Bob.

The probability that Alice tosses $k$ heads and Bob tosses $k$ heads
is the same as
the probability that Alice tosses $k$ heads and Bob tosses $k$ tails,
that is the same as
the probability that Alice tosses $k$ heads and Bob tosses $n-k$ heads.

Adding up over all $k$,
he probability that Alice and Bob toss the same number of heads
is the same as
the probability that Alice and Bob toss $n$ heads between them.

Comment: Nice use of words.

Answer (score 0):

Use combinational formula $C_n^k = C_n^{n-k}$ to reduce computation by half. The probability is $$p = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}{(C_n^i)}^2}{2^{2n}} = \frac{C_{2n}^n}{2^{2n}}.$$